# Using intel compiler in atom editor

Tags: atom-editor, intel-fortran

My .bashrc contains a line like:

```
source /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2016/linux/bin/compilervars.sh intel64
```

and now I would like to compile my program from atom using atom-build, so I have the following file in my atom-build.yml:

```
cmd: ifort main.f90
```

and if I then run Ctrl+Alt+b the error is:

```
/bin/sh: 1: ifort: not found
```

If I start atom from the console this problem doesn't exist. How do I run ifort from atom without using the console?

Comment: What version of Atom are you running? As of 1.8.0, this should be fixed via [#11054](https://github.com/atom/atom/pull/11054) if I'm understanding correctly. If you open Atom *not* from the console, does `process.env` (run from the Chrome debugging tools) have the expected environment variables (*from* the interactive shell environment)?

Comment: My version is 1.8.0. I'm not sure what you are referring to with the last part is there some tutorial for this.